# Custom Annotation for timestamping a method

Tags: java, annotations, timestamp, interceptor

Java Gurus,

I am pretty new for `annotations` so please bear with me...

I would like to implement a `Custom Annotation` which will `intercept` a method call and just print the time taken by the method. Is it possible?

```
@EnableElapsedTime
public MyAppObject findMyAppObjectById(Long id) throws MyCustomException {
    //....
}
```

should print something like this in the logs:

```
findMyAppObjectById() took 2.345 sec.
```

Can I get some hints around this?

Comment: The answer is no and yes. You can't do  that with just annotations, but you can do it with annotations, plus Aspects. (if you use Spring this become easier). I know it's not a full response, but hopefully you'll be able to steer in the right direction :).

Answer (score 2):

An annotation on its own cannot do that. You need to investigate a technique called "Aspect Oriented Programming" (or AOP).

Comment: for Java, check out AspectJ or Spring

Answer (score 1):

[Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) does the same thing with @Profiled annotation and provides many other unobtrusive profiling options.